# Grouping specific values from an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Say I have an array such as this:

```
namesscore = ["Rory: 1", "Rory: 4", "Liam: 5", "Liam: 6", "Erin: 8", "Liam: 2",]
```

and I wanted to sort that array to make it like this:

```
namescore = ["Rory: 1, 4", "Liam: 5, 6, 2", "Erin: 8"]
```

How would I do that?

Comment: It seems like you want a dictionary using the name as a key and assign them a list value that you can use append on.

Comment: By what criteria is the final array being sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namesscore = ["Rory: 1", "Rory: 4", "Liam: 5", "Liam: 6", "Erin: 8", "Liam: 2"]
namesscore = [tuple(el.split()) for el in namesscore]
temp = dict((el[1], el[0]) for el in namesscore)

merge = {}
for key, value in temp.iteritems():
    if value not in merge:
        merge[value] = [key]
    else:
        merge[value].append(key)

print [' '.join((k, ' '.join(v))) for k, v in merge.iteritems()]

>>> ['Rory: 1 4', 'Liam: 2 5 6', 'Erin: 8']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd iterate the list, and for each item split it between the name and a score. Then I'd create a dict (more accurately: an `OrderedDict`, to preserve the order) and accumulate the scores for each name. When the iteration is done, it can be converted to a list of strings in the desired format:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def group_scores(namesscore):
    mapped = OrderedDict()
    for elem in namesscore:
        name, score = elem.split(': ')
        if name not in mapped:
            mapped[name] = []
        mapped[name].append(score)

    return ['%s%s%s' % (key, ': ', ', '.join(value)) for \
              key, value in mapped.items()]
```

Comment: This returns "AttributeError: 'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'"

Comment: @Liwa didn't notice the [tag:python3] tag, mea culpa. I edited and replaced the `iteritems()` call with `items()`, which should work on both python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
namesscore = ["Rory: 1", "Rory: 4", "Liam: 5", "Liam: 6", "Erin: 8", "Liam: 2",]

od = {}

[ od.setdefault(a,[]).append(b) for a,b in map(lambda x : (x[0:x.find(':')],x[-1]), namesscore)]

namesscore = ['  '.join((k,' '.join(sorted(v))))  for k, v in od.items()]

print(namesscore)

['Erin  8', 'Liam  2 5 6', 'Rory  1 4']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import operator

namesscore = ["Rory: 1", "Rory: 4", "Liam: 5", "Liam: 6", "Erin: 8", "Liam: 2",]

# Build a dictionary where the key is the name and the value is a list of scores
scores = defaultdict(list)
for ns in namesscore:
    name, score = ns.split(':')
    scores[name].append(score)

# Sort each persons scores
scores = {n: sorted(s) for n, s in scores.items()}   

# Sort people by their scores returning a list of tuples
scores = sorted(scores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))   

# Output the final strings
scores = ['{}: {}'.format(n, ', '.join(s)) for n, s in scores]

print scores

> ['Rory:  1,  4', 'Liam:  2,  5,  6', 'Erin:  8']
```

Comment: This returns "["L_K: {'4'}", "L_K: {'2'}", "L_K: {'0'}", "L_K: {'1'}", "Rory_Follin: {'2'}", "Rory_Follin: {'2'}", "Rory_Follin: {'10'}"]" when run through my prgram

Comment: @Liwa Can you post your initial `namesscore` list? It appears your values and maybe the structure are different from your example.